# Delete all git branches which have been merged - Fatal: branch name required?

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, pruning

I'm trying to delete all of my merged branches. I've always used

`git branch --merged | egrep -v "(^\*|master|dev)" | xargs git branch -d` but for some reason it won't work anymore, even though I've used this command before. It returns the error "Fatal: branch name required"

Comment: Try leaving out the `| xargs git branch -d`. If that does not explain it, try leaving out the `egrep` as well, for more illumination.

Answer (score 15):

If there is no input provided on `stdin` -- for example, if the preceding pipeline produces no output -- `xargs` will run your command with no arguments.  That is, if this:

```
git branch --merged | egrep -v "(^\*|master|dev)"
```

Produces no output, then `xargs` will run:

```
git branch -d
```

Which, if you were to try that yourself on the command line, produces:

```
fatal: branch name required
```

The easiest solution is to add the `--no-run-if-empty` flag to `xargs`:

```
git branch --merged |
 egrep -v "(^\*|master|dev)" |
 xargs --no-run-if-empty git branch -d
```

Comment: Thanks for adding in the case of there being no other branches to delete!